# How to return only specific properties from Azure Devops REST APIs

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops

I am trying to fetch all build details for a particular project in Azure devops using 
`GET: https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1`

This API returns a JSON object with many properties. In Jenkins APIs we have a provision to filter only the required properties.
Is there a similar way in Azure Devops APIs?

As per the docs `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1`, I have tried using the `propertyFilter` but didn't help me out.

Any help or pointers will be useful.

Comment: Hi @Likhith Prakash The properties query in the URI Parameters may not be the build's properties. As workaround, you can use script to filter the properties from the returned build results. Please check out the powershell script example in below answer.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON that is returned from DevOps looks pretty much like this:

```
{
  "count": 1000,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": ,
      "buildNumber": "",
      "status": "",
      "result": "",
      "queueTime": "",
      "startTime": "",
      "finishTime": "",
      "url": "",
      "definition": {
        "drafts": [

        ],
        "id": ,
        "name": "",
        "url": "",
        "uri": "",
        "path": "",
        "type": "",
        "queueStatus": "",
        "revision": ,
        "project": {
          "id": "",
          "name": "<NAMEOFYOURPROJECT>",
          "url": "",
          "state": "",
          "revision": ,
          "visibility": "",
          "lastUpdateTime": ""
        }
      },
      "buildNumberRevision": 2,
      "project": {
        "id": "",
        "name": "<NAMEOFYOURPROJECT>",
        "url": "",
        "state": "",
        "revision": ,
        "visibility": "",
        "lastUpdateTime": "2"
      },
      ...
```

The key your are looking for to filter is `project/name`.

Your ODATA query string to filter for `project/name` would look like this:
`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1&$filter=startswith(project/name,'<NAMEOFYOURPROJECT>')`

Answer (score 0):

The `properties` query in the URI Parameters may not be the properties of the returned response json as what we think it is. It might be the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#propertiescollection) in the property `properties` of returned build results.

As workaround, you can write scripts to filter the required properties from the returned build results. Please check below example in powershell scripts:

```
$url ="https://dev.azure.com/{OGR}/{PROJ}/_apis/build/builds?`$top=5&api-version=5.1"
$PAT="PAT"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $murl -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method get 

# filter the requested properties from the result
$requiredProperties = $result.value | select {$_.project.name}, {$_.definition.name}, id, buildNumber  

$requiredProperties
```

Above scripts get the top 5 builds' results and use script (`$result.value | select {$_.project.name}, {$_.definition.name}, id, buildNumber`) to select the required properties afterwards. You will see the selected properties as below screenshot:

[image]

Hope above helps!